# Is there a utility to compare two JSON strings?

Tags: json, web

I'm writing a function that generates a json string, this function is aimed to replace old one. So I need to make sure that JSON that my function outputs is identical to JSON of the old function. Is there an utility to check identity of two JSON trees?

Comment: isnt it both String Compare ?

Comment: There might be a better library for just this purpose, but if the JSON generators are using exactly the same generation rules (ie, all double-quotes, no whitespace) then you might be able to just do regular string comparison in whatever language you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [JSON Diff](http://tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff/) before, just compare the output from the old JSON function and your new one to see if they match up. Make sure to test with more complex data structures too.